# Process.Start() only after current application killed

Tags: c#, cmd

Is it possible for a running c# application to start/invoke some new arbitrary process, but only do so after the current running application is terminated?

I guess it's possible to call the new process from `Process.Start()` via `cmd.exe` and do something like `sleep 3 & c:\mynewapplication.exe` - this would giver the 'caller' some three seconds to terminate itself.

However this is a bit hacky, and was wondering if there was a neater way?

Comment: This sounds like the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Perhaps try to describe what you're trying to do, not how you want it done.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the type of application, you could simply listen to the end of the program. One option you have is the [`Application.ApplicationExit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.applicationexit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event.

Another possibility is to start another process, that waits until the first process dies. You could poll [`Process.GetProcesses`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for example. This will raise the event, even if the first process crashes. You could also register the [`Process.Exited`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event.

Comment: @maxp need more help?

Answer (score 0):

It has little to do with C#. It is a question about the Windows OS, and, in particular, in WinAPI.

Generally, the only 'thing' that runs code is threads. When your process in terminated, all its threads die.

Your best approach is probably by starting a process that will wait before starting your new process, as you suggested, however you may, for example, hook on some of the functions called when something happens and start your new process there.